# How to fix a broken import in PyLance (code works in Python)

Tags: python-3.x, stripe-payments

Pylance does not like this import

[image: screenshot]

```
from stripe.api_resources.test_helpers import TestClock as StripeTestClock
```

Even though the files exist and python can find them.  I get no errors for `stripe.Customer`, `stripe.Product`, `stripe.Price`

```
lib/python3.10/site-packages/stripe/api_resources/test_helpers/__init__.py:6:from stripe.api_resources.test_helpers.test_clock import TestClock
```

If I open this file, pylance gripes about the import there too.  Something is stopping it from seeing these import paths even though it is happy with `import stripe`